# How to test window.pageYoffset with webdriverIO and chai

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, chai

For a selenium test with WebDriverIO and Chai, i need the position of window.pageYoffset. In WebDriverIO i couldn't found a way to do this. I tried:

```
browser.scroll(0, 200);
browser.getAttribute('window','pageYoffset');
```

Throw an error : An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters ("window").

So, next try:

```
browser.scroll(0, 200);
browser.windowHandlePosition();
```

Return an object :

```
{
sessionID: ...,
value: {x :10, y: 10,
_status: 0
}
```

Normaly the **value.y** attribute must be 200 insteed of 10.

To work with **element()** or **$()** brings the same error like in the first example.

When i search with google, i couldn't find a solution, so i hope to find help by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Read API: http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html

You are trying to get attribute of `window` but window is selector for WebElement

Probably you need to execute Javascript inside browser and return value of it.
For example:

```
browser.scroll(0, 250);

let result = browser.execute(function() {
   return window.pageYOffset;
})

console.log(result.value); // 250
```